# AutoLayout programmatically doesn't work

Tags: ios, autolayout, programmatically-created

I want to go into the depths of auto layout and so I want to do it programmatically in order to understand it properly.I know how to use it through storyboard pretty well.Now here is what I am doing(in `viewDidAppear:`)

```
-(void)scenario2{

    PGView *viewA = [[PGView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100) andBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:viewA];

    PGView *viewB = [[PGView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 300, 100, 100) andBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:viewB];

    viewA.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    viewB.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    NSLayoutConstraint *constraint;

    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[viewB(==100)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(viewB)]];

    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[viewB(==100)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(viewB)]];

    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[viewA(==200)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(viewA)]];
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[viewA(==200)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(viewA)]];

    //problem statement
    constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:viewA attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:viewB attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplier: 3.0f constant: 0.0f];
    [self.view addConstraint:constraint];

    NSLog(@"%@",viewA);
    NSLog(@"%@",viewB);

}
```

1. So here I have initialized two views with different colors.
2. I know I need to set the property. `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `NO` before applying any new constraints. So I have done that.
3. Now I am specifying heights and widths of both the views.So,the x_position and y_position for both the views are 0.I run the code and I get the expected result. Both views have the specified height and width at point (0,0).

Problem

4. Now when I am writing the statement "problem statement" to adjust the width of viewB according to the width of viewA,its not working.
5. Also, when I print views viewA and viewB,it prints the frames as (0,0,0,0).

Can anyone explain me this behavior?

Edit:Here are some modifications that I have made.I have checked the ambiguity of both the views using 'hasAmbiguousLayout' and its working fine now.Now what should be the next step if I want to resize viewB's width thrice to that of viewA's width?

```
-(void)scenario2{

PGView *viewA = [PGView new];
viewA.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
[self.view addSubview:viewA];

PGView *viewB = [PGView new];
viewB.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[self.view addSubview:viewB];

viewA.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
viewB.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

NSLayoutConstraint *constraint;

[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-[viewB(==100)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(viewB)]];
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[viewB(==100)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(viewB)]];

[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-[viewA(==200)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(viewA)]];
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[viewA(==200)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(viewA)]];


NSLog(@"%d",viewA.hasAmbiguousLayout);
NSLog(@"%d",viewB.hasAmbiguousLayout);

NSLog(@"%@",viewA);
NSLog(@"%@",viewB);

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you've explicitly set width constraints for A and B to be 200 and 100, respectively. So the additional constraint that specifies that one should have a width of three times the other one is unsatisfiable when combined with the other constraints.

Furthermore, the constraints are ambiguous, as you've defined width and height constraints, but haven't defined *where* the two frames should be. Yes, you've defined the `frame` for these two views, but that is ignored when you apply the constraints. You probably shouldn't define the `frame` values at all, as it's misleading and confusing. But you should set, for example, the leading and top constraints, or specify those in the VFL, or add `centerX` and `centerY` constraints. You just want some constraints to dictate where the views should be placed and there's lots of ways to specify that.

And the reason that you're not seeing reasonable `frame` values at the end is that you've defined the constraints, but they haven't been applied yet. You could examine them in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, if you wanted.

---

You might do something like:

```
- (void)scenario2 {

    PGView *viewA = [PGView new];
    viewA.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    [self.view addSubview:viewA];

    PGView *viewB = [PGView new];
    viewB.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [self.view addSubview:viewB];

    viewA.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    viewB.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(viewA, viewB);

    // note, I added `|-100-` to say it's 100 points from the top (and 100 tall)

    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-100-[viewB(==100)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];

    // likewise, to say 200 points from the left (and 100 wide)

    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-200-[viewB(==100)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];

    // again, 100 from the top (as well as 200 tall)

    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-100-[viewA(==200)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];

    // and 100 from the left
    // but I've removed width definition, as we'll use your multiplier constraint below

    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-100-[viewA]" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];

    // now that we've removed the width constraint from the above,
    // this should now work fine

    NSLayoutConstraint *constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:viewA attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:viewB attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplier: 3.0f constant: 0.0f];
    [self.view addConstraint:constraint];

    // no point in doing this, because constraints haven't yet been applied
    //
    // NSLog(@"%@",viewA);
    // NSLog(@"%@",viewB);
}

// if you want to see where they are, you could do that here:

- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    for (UIView *view in self.view.subviews) {
        NSLog(@"%@", view);
    }
    NSLog(@"-----");
}
```

Comment: I have updated my question with some modifications in my code.Can you please explain this ?

Comment: @Reckoner - OK, so, like in my code snippet above, remove the width definition from the VFL for A, and then you can use your multiplier constraint. Now, I defined leading and top constraints (which I inferred from your attempt to set the frame), which you didn't use in your edit, but hopefully this is still clear enough to illustrate my point.

Comment: I stir have one question though......When i print viewA and viewB in my code at the end,why does it print the frame as (0 0;0 0)?